# ¿Cómo mantener los productos de un carrito on-line después de un cierre del navegador?

Tags: php

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación web de un carrito on-line donde los usuarios registrados pueden añadir productos al carrito, así como realizar compras en linea.
El problema que tengo es que cuando se cierra el navegador, los artículos que se almacenaron en el carrito on-line desaparecen, es decir, el carrito se vacía.
Hasta el momento estoy usando variables de sesión y sí funciona del todo, pero el problema que ví fue:

1. Al finalizar la sesion del usuario, el carrito se vacía.
     (El carrito no se debe vacíar sino mantenerse y que al volver a hacer login los articulos que el cliente eligió aparezcan en su carrito)
2. Al cerrar el navegador, el carrito se vacía.

Por favor, ¿alguien puede aclarme de qué estoy haciendo mal?, o mi lógica no es la correcta.

Comment: Almacénalos en la base de datos, así no solo te aseguras de que persistan los datos en su carrito, si no que no que no importa si inicia sesión en otro navegador o dispositivo, mantendrá sus artículos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema de las variables de sesión (en tu caso), es que cuando se cierra el navegador, estas son borradas. Lo que debes hacer es almacenar la información en una Base de Datos, para que persistan los datos y sin importar cuantas veces se cierre el navegador o desde que computadora se abra sesión podrás recuperar los artículos.

Ahora bien, puedes usar las variables de sesión, para no estar consultando la Base de Datos cada vez que se cambia de página, pero sí cada vez que se agrega algo al carrito o se borra, deberías hacer la modificación en la Variable de Sesión y también en la base de datos, además de que cuando el usuario inicia sesión, consultar lo último que dejó en el carrito.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, solo que ¿a qué te refieres con modificar la variable de sesión? Hasta el momento yo estoy usando dos variables, 1: sesion del cliente, 2: sesion del carrito, pero mi duda es a que te refieres con modificar la variable de sesión

Comment: Por ejemplo, sí vas a agregar un nuevo producto, agregas a la variable de sesión algún registro que identifique ese artículo, al hacer esta modificación en la variable de sesión, también deberías hacerla en alguna tabla en donde guardes ese registro.

Comment: Gracias, me has aclarado mis dudas

Comment: Un gusto, me alegra haber ayudado.